# Trouble embedding chessboard.js

Tags: javascript

I would like to make use of the wonderful looking chessboard available at chessboard.js. However, after downloading the folder and entering the code offered on the home page, it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Is there something beyond the linking to the folders that is required?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Ask A GM</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/chessboard-0.3.0.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/chessboard-0.3.0.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="chessboard-0.3.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="chessboard-0.3.0.min.js"></script>




</head>
<body>

<div id="board2" style="width: 400px"></div>
<input type="button" id="startBtn" value="Start" />
<input type="button" id="clearBtn" value="Clear" />

<script>
var board2 = ChessBoard('board2', {
  draggable: true,
  dropOffBoard: 'trash',
  sparePieces: true
});
$('#startBtn').on('click', board2.start);
$('#clearBtn').on('click', board2.clear);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is causing an issue but you have the JS and CSS files linked twice - the uncompressed and the minified versions (.min just means it is the same file, but compressed). Link only the .min versions of each if you don't plan on editing the code at all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing jQuery and you should throw your javascript in a document ready function like so:

http://jsbin.com/mapenefesi/edit?html,css,js,output

```
  $(function(){
    var board2 = ChessBoard('board2', {
      draggable: true,
      dropOffBoard: 'trash',
      sparePieces: true
    });
    $('#startBtn').on('click', board2.start);
    $('#clearBtn').on('click', board2.clear);
  });
```

Comment: I missed the jQuery reference! :) But I'm not sure it's necessary to utilize the `document.ready` event in this case.

Comment: @m-albert Yeah, normally I wouldn't think so either, but the demo I threw together didn't work without it.  I feel ashamed for saying this, but I can't go debug it right now.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you want both `.css` and `.min.css` as well as `.js` and `.min.js` references of the same resources.

Also, since you're not referencing jQuery (as mentioned in some other answers), you'll need to change your javascript...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ask A GM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/chessboard-0.3.0.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="chessboard-0.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="board2" style="width: 400px"></div>
    <input type="button" id="startBtn" value="Start" />
    <input type="button" id="clearBtn" value="Clear" />

    <script>
        var board2 = ChessBoard('board2', {
            draggable: true,
            dropOffBoard: 'trash',
            sparePieces: true
        });
        document.getElementById('startBtn').click = function() { board2.start; };
        document.getElementById('clearBtn').click = function() { board2.clear; };
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using jQuery selectors (e.g. `$('#startBtn')`) without including the jQuery library https://jquery.com/. Try including...

`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>`